# AWS deploy app in multiple regions with multiple hosted zones

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-route53

If I want to deploy my app to multiple regions, how can I do this with route 53? The setup is as follows:

```
I want to deploy to regions A, B and C with a domain (domain.com)
I have web servers A, B, C which are running my app in regions A, B, C
how can I ensure that the client is served by the server which is geographically closest
(assuming they enter (domain.com) in their browser)?
```

I currently have one hosted zone which points to a server in one region. But this does not give me the desired behavior of routing to the closest server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `GeoLocation` routing in Route53. See [Geolocation routing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-geo) or [Geoproximity routing (traffic flow only)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-geoproximity).